# ACL laravel por campo

Tags: laravel, acl

Existe alguma solução para controle de acesso por *input*?

Exemplo: um determinado usuário pode acessar um form mas não pode acessar determinado campo, já outro usuário pode acessar o mesmo form e ter acesso ao campo em questão.

Comment: Eu acredito que esse tipo de controle é efetivado no _client-side_. Talvez com JavaScript...

Comment: Mas aí o usuário vai ter acesso pra burlar

Comment: Não tem como fazer isso no PHP. Vc  pode definir nas ACLS algumas regras para **não carregar os campos** pra um determinado usuário. Mas PHP não vai controlar o comportamento do FORM. Quem controla o FORM é o navegador, e o navegador conversa com JavaScript e HTML.

Comment: O _model_ tb pode proibir a edição de determinados campos com base nas suas regras de acesso. E em PHP, é o que dá (creio).

Comment: Primeira pergunta? Como está fazendo sua autenticação ? e após isso, está usando alguma técnica para autorização ? são coisas complementares mas, em momentos diferentes! sua pergunta é muito ampla, poderia colocar um exemplo minimo e real, talvez consigamos direcionar!